# Compare dates with different formats in csv file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Whats a good way to compare dates in a csv file that looks like this:

```
Date1,Date2,Date3
11/10/2016  9:45:00 PM,20161110,11/10/2016
11/15/2016  11:24:00 PM,20160924,11/10/2016
```

If a match is found, append a column like so...

```
Date1,Date2,Date3,MatchDates
11/10/2016  9:45:00 PM,20161110,11/10/2016,Match Found
11/15/2016  11:24:00 PM,20160924,11/10/2016,No Match Found
```

## updated

Trying the code that is in the comments:

When comparing this with 2 of the columns...

```
$csvFile = 'C:\Scripts\Tests\test1.csv'

Import-Csv $csvFile | Select-Object *, @{n='MatchDates';e={
if(([datetime]$_.Date1).Date -eq $_.Date3){
'Match Found'
}Else{
'No Match Found'
}}} | 
    Export-Csv "$csvFile-results.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

output (isCorrect)...

```
Date1,Date2,Date3,MatchDates
11/10/2016  9:45:00 PM,20161110,11/10/2016,Match Found
11/15/2016  11:24:00 PM,20160924,11/10/2016,No Match Found
```

However, if I try to compare all 3 columns using the following code

```
Import-Csv $csvFile | Select-Object *, @{n='MatchDates';e={
if((([datetime]$_.Date1).Date -eq $_.Date3) -and (([datetime]$_.Date2).Date -eq $_.Date3) -and (([datetime]$_.Date1).Date -eq $_.Date2)){
'Match Found'
}Else{
'No Match Found'
}}} | 
    Export-Csv "$csvFile-results.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

output (isNotCorrect)...

```
Date1,Date2,Date3,MatchDates
11/10/2016  9:45:00 PM,20161110,11/10/2016,
11/15/2016  11:24:00 PM,20160924,11/10/2016,No Match Found
```

As you can see the value of row 1 and the last column is `$null` instead of showing `Match Found`

Maybe I'm not understanding something correctly?

Comment: Cast as [datetime] or use [datetime]::parseexact()?

Comment: That is of course assuming these dates are all of the same format. Also you are comparing the date in the first column to see if it matches the date in the last column? If the are formatted the same you could almost just get away with basic `-like`

Comment: `([datetime]"11/10/2016  9:45:00 PM").Date -eq "11/10/2016"` for example. or `([datetime]$_.Date1).Date -eq $_.Date3`

Comment: Tbh, I am going to need to figure out if they match based upon a 2 day grace period. But this part was not part of the question, the first part is basically formalizing them so they can be read the same. Creating the tests now...

Comment: That logic has very little difference on the out come here.... Just something like this instead. `[datetime]"11/10/2016 9:45:00 PM" - [datetime]"11/10/2016" | select -expand days`... The math based on that is not much a bigger stretch.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with what we discussed in comments. Problem was with that middle date. It does not convert to a [datetime] without some help. That is where `ParseExact` comes in handy. Consider the following:

```
PS D:\temp> [datetime]"20160924"
Cannot convert value "20160924" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
+ [datetime]"20160924"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider


PS D:\temp> [datetime]::parseexact("20160924","yyyyMMdd",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)

Saturday, September 24, 2016 12:00:00 AM
```

Note the second example returned a proper date object.

---

Do you remember the [transitive property](http://www.mathwords.com/t/transitive_property.htm) from math? We use that for simple comparison to see if all dates are the same. Not the only way by far but a simple one nonetheless. Building off your calculated property code

```
$csv |  Select-Object *,@{Name='MatchDates';Expression={
        $date1 = ([datetime]$_.Date1).Date
        $date2 = ([datetime]::parseexact($_.Date2,"yyyyMMdd",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)).Date
        $date3 = ([datetime]$_.Date1).Date
        if($date1 -eq $date2 -and $date2 -eq $date3){
            'Match Found'
        } else {
            'No Match Found'
        }
    }
}
```

Cleared up the `if` logic by saving the casted values in temproary variables.

Comment: Yup, the comparison works well, although you are also right with if (date1 = date3) and (date2 = date3), then there is no need to check if (date1 = date3). However (and this is my fault for not including it in the question), with the 2day grace period for every date, it is possible to have a missmatch. That is why using the `ParseExact` will still be usefull. Thanks again :)

Comment: @FiddleFreak So you would consider a match if the dates were all at most 2 days off from eachother?