# Append existing column in csv by matching values with array and with condition

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I will do my best to break this down as simply as I can.

## what I have so far that is working:

Currently I have two csv files...

test1.csv

```
test1ColumnN,test1ColumnI,test1ColumnD,selectDomainOne,selectDomainTwo,selectDomainThree
asdf,asdf,asdf,,,
nValue1,iValue1,dValue1,sValue1,,
qwer,asdf,zxcv,,,
nValue2,iValue2,dValue2,,,
qwer,zxcv,asdf,lkjh,,
nValue3,iValue3,dValue3,sValue3,,
zxcv,qwer,asdf,,poiu,
nValue1,iValue1,dValue1,,sValue1,
nValue4,iValue4,dValue4,,sValue4,
asdf,qwer,zxcv,fghj,mnbv,
nValue5,iValue5,dValue5,,,
asdf,cvbn,erty,,,uytr
nValue7,iValue7,dValue7,,,sValue7
nValue8,iValue8,dValue8,,,sValue8
nValue9,iValue9,dValue9,,,sValue9
qwer,asdf,zxcv,poiu,lkjh,mnbv
```

test2.csv

```
DomainCatagories,test2ColumnS,test2ColumnA,test2ColumnN,test2ColumnI,test2ColumnD
DomainOne,sValue1,aValue1,nValue1,,dValueN
DomainOne,sValue2,aValue2,,iValue2,dValue2
DomainOne,sValue3,aValue2,nValue3,iValue3,dValue3
DomainTwo,sValue1,aValue2,,iValue1,dValueN
DomainTwo,sValue4,aValue1,nValue4,,dValueN
DomainTwo,sValue5,aValue1,nValue5,iValue5,dValue5
DomainThree,sValue7,aValue2,nValue7,iValue7,dValue7
DomainThree,sValue8,aValue1,nValue8,iValue8,dValue8
DomainThree,sValue9,aValue2,nValue9,iValue9,dValue9
```

Now I want to add a column (inside test2.csv) to match the `sValue#` from both test1.csv and test2.csv with the condition of (`$_.DomainCatagories='DomainOne'` from test2.csv) and (`$_.selectDomainOne` from test1.csv)

To do this, I am using the following code...

```
#Create Column
$domainNameOne = @{}
$domainNameOne = Import-Csv 'C:\Scripts\Tests\test1.csv' | Where-Object {$_.selectDomainOne} | Select-Object -Expand 'selectDomainOne'

(Import-Csv 'C:\Scripts\Tests\test2.csv') | 
    Select-Object -Property *, @{n='Test1sValues';e={
    if($_.DomainCatagories -eq 'DomainOne'){
        if(($domainNameOne -contains $_.test2ColumnS) -and ($_.test2ColumnS)){
            $_.test2ColumnS
        } Else {
            'Not found in test1'
    }}}} | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\Tests\test2-Temp" -NoType
    Move-Item "C:\Scripts\Tests\test2-Temp" 'C:\Scripts\Tests\test2.csv' -Force
```

After the code is run, I get the following test2.csv (isCorrect)...

```
"DomainCatagories","test2ColumnS","test2ColumnA","test2ColumnN","test2ColumnI","test2ColumnD","Test1sValues"
"DomainOne","sValue1","aValue1","nValue1","","dValueN","sValue1"
"DomainOne","sValue2","aValue2","","iValue2","dValue2","Not found in test1"
"DomainOne","sValue3","aValue2","nValue3","iValue3","dValue3","sValue3"
"DomainTwo","sValue1","aValue2","","iValue1","dValueN",""
"DomainTwo","sValue4","aValue1","nValue4","","dValueN",""
"DomainTwo","sValue5","aValue1","nValue5","iValue5","dValue5",""
"DomainThree","sValue7","aValue2","nValue7","iValue7","dValue7",""
"DomainThree","sValue8","aValue1","nValue8","iValue8","dValue8",""
"DomainThree","sValue9","aValue2","nValue9","iValue9","dValue9",""
```

## What I have that is not working:

Next I run the following code...

```
#Append Column
$domainNameThree = @{}
$domainNameThree = Import-Csv 'C:\Scripts\Tests\test1.csv' | Where-Object {$_.selectDomainThree} | Select-Object -Expand 'selectDomainThree'

(Import-Csv 'C:\Scripts\Tests\test2.csv') | % {
    if($_.DomainCatagories -eq 'DomainThree'){
        if(($domainNameThree -contains $_.test2ColumnS) -and ($_.test2ColumnS)){
            $_.Test1sValues = $_.test2ColumnS
        } Else {
            $_.Test1sValues = 'Not found in test1'
    }}} | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\Tests\test2-Temp" -NoType
Move-Item "C:\Scripts\Tests\test2-Temp" 'C:\Scripts\Tests\test2.csv' -Force
```

Instead of adding the values in the correct rows, it completely blanks out the whole file and saves it as an `empty file`.

## End Goal

What I want the code to produce, is this (notice values filled in on last 3 rows in the last column)...

```
"DomainCatagories","test2ColumnS","test2ColumnA","test2ColumnN","test2ColumnI","test2ColumnD","Test1sValues"
"DomainOne","sValue1","aValue1","nValue1","","dValueN","sValue1"
"DomainOne","sValue2","aValue2","","iValue2","dValue2","Not found in test1"
"DomainOne","sValue3","aValue2","nValue3","iValue3","dValue3","sValue3"
"DomainTwo","sValue1","aValue2","","iValue1","dValueN",""
"DomainTwo","sValue4","aValue1","nValue4","","dValueN",""
"DomainTwo","sValue5","aValue1","nValue5","iValue5","dValue5",""
"DomainThree","sValue7","aValue2","nValue7","iValue7","dValue7","sValue7"
"DomainThree","sValue8","aValue1","nValue8","iValue8","dValue8","sValue8"
"DomainThree","sValue9","aValue2","nValue9","iValue9","dValue9","sValue9"
```

What am I doing wrong in that 2nd code snippet?

Comment: @RyanBemrose The code is reproducible with the two given files. I don't see what the issue is with my question.

Comment: Seems fine to me. Ryan might have an issue with the _Minimal_ part of MCVE

Comment: In your not working example you are not passing anything to the pipe. `}} $_} | Export-Csv "C:\Scripts\Tests\test2-Temp" -NoType` could work if the brackets are right. That should output the updated object back into the pipe. You could also use a calculated property like [I have seen you do before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423960/compare-dates-with-different-formats-in-csv-file) or `Add-Member`

Comment: You also made `$domainNameThree = @{}` a empty hashtable. Might not matter but you are treating it like an array so `$domainNameThree = @()` makes sense.

Comment: ah perfect, thanks Matt. It works perfectly :) The passing of the pipe is what fixed it. also fyi I had to add a `;` in `}};$_} | Export-Csv`. As for the hash vs array I'm not sure about if it matters too with hash vs array, but I'll change it and test it again. In any case the missing of the pipe return is definitely the answer. Thanks again :)

Comment: yeah creating an empty hash or array isn't even needed since it's not being called before it's initialized. So I just removed the line `$domainNameThree = @{}`

Answer (score 0):

The example you show from *What I have that is not working:* is missing a key portion. `Export-Csv` will take everything piped into it to populate the CSV but you are not providing any.

Problem is that you are not passing anything through the pipe. Merely just updating one property. The simplest thing to do is add `$_` after the `if` statement. Or you could just use a calculated property which you have done before in another one of your questions. The example below from [Compare dates with different formats in csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423960/compare-dates-with-different-formats-in-csv-file) even uses an if statement.

> ```
> Import-Csv $csvFile | Select-Object *, @{n='MatchDates';e={ if((([datetime]$_.Date1).Date -eq $_.Date3) -and (([datetime]$_.Date2).Date -eq $_.Date3) -and (([datetime]$_.Date1).Date -eq $_.Date2)){ 'Match Found' }Else{ 'No Match Found' }}} | 
>     Export-Csv "$csvFile-results.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
> ```